# IOS set and get property on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to initialize a couple properties fetched from parse.com when the view is loaded so I can do calculation with them. For instance, I declare the following in my header file:

```
TaskViewController.h

@property (nonatomic, assign) int taskTotalCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int taskCompletedCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int progressCount;


- (void)CountAndSetTotalTask;
- (void)CountAndSetCompletedCount;
- (void)CalculateProgress;
```

Then in the implementation, assuming all the other initialization are setup properly and they are called in viewdidload, below are the method implementations:

```
TaskViewController.m

- (void)CountAndSetCompletedCount {
    // Query the tasks objects that are marked completed and count them
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"Goal" equalTo:self.tasks];
    [query whereKey:@"completed" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // The count request succeeded. Assign it to taskCompletedCount
            self.taskCompletedCount = count;

            NSLog(@"total completed tasks for this goal = %d", self.taskCompletedCount);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Fail to retrieve task count");
        }
    }];

}

- (void)CountAndSetTotalTask {
    // Count the number of total tasks for this goal
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"Goal" equalTo:self.tasks];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // The count request succeeded. Assign it to taskTotalCount
            self.taskTotalCount = count;

            NSLog(@"total tasks for this goal = %d", self.taskTotalCount);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Fail to retrieve task count");
        }
    }];
}

- (void)CalculateProgress {
    int x = self.taskCompletedCount;
    int y = self.taskTotalCount;
    NSLog(@"the x value is %d", self.taskCompletedCount);
    NSLog(@"the y value is %d", self.taskTotalCount);
    if (!y==0) {
        self.progressCount = ceil(x/y); 
    } else {
        NSLog(@"one number is 0");
    }

    NSLog(@"The progress count is = %d", self.progressCount);
}
```

The issue I am encountering is that the taskTotalCount and taskCompletedCount are set correctly and returns different numbers in the first two methods while the NSLog returns 0 for both x and y. Therefore I'm not sure if the third method somehow got loaded before the two properties are set or it's some other issues. Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Show how you call these three methods.

Comment: I called it the same way as you pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call these three methods like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self CountAndSetCompletedCount];
    [self CountAndSetTotalTask];
    [self CalculateProgress];
}
```

then the problem is that the first two methods return immediately while the calls to Parse occur in the background. This means that `CalculateProgress` is called long before you get back the results from the calls to Parse.

One solution is to just call `CountAndSetCompletedCount` from `viewDidLoad`. In its completion handler you then call `CountAndSetTotalTask`. In its completion handler you finally call `CalculateProgress`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, let me give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Yep that was it. CalculatedProgress is called before the results were fetched. All I had to do was call the CalculateProgress method after the other methods are completed. Thanks again!